# Cloud IoT Config encryption

Tags: google-cloud-iot

I want to send sensitive data through Cloud IoT Config, but not sure of if there is any encryption. Is there any form of encryption that happens for config messages between server and device?

Any references?

Answer (score 0):

It does support TLS encryption, I've only implemented this over MQTT.

I'd recommend going over this page: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/device-security